# how to trigger discord comand using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, bots

I want to send commands like (/imagine prompt:) in discord using python requests. I've been looking for a lot of information on this but haven't figured out how to do it. If it is not difficult for you could share the code ?

I tried to copy the official post request that discord sends but the command was not sent.

Comment: do you understand self-botting is violating the tos?

Comment: Yes, but there are those who use this method for e.g. Midjourney's api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
header = {
            'authorization': <your_token>
        }
payload = {'type': 2, 
        'application_id': '',
        'guild_id': '',
        'channel_id': '',
        'session_id': '',
        'data': {
            'version': '',
            'id': '',
            'name': '<command name>,
            'type': 1,
            'options': [{'type': 3, 'name': 'prompt', 'value': ''}],
            'attachments': []}
            }
        
r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions', json = payload , headers = header)
```

try this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).